# Trying to load category thumbnails on wordpress page

Tags: php

I'm trying to show some Wordpress category thumbnails on my homepage, but it seems my code is breaking the rest of my site. It kills the page and anything under my code won't load.

Any help would be appreciated on how to get this working.

Thanks!

```
<?php

    global $post;
    $temp_post = $post;
    $args = array('numberposts' => 1, 'category' => 40, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC');
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumbnail = get_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
        $title = get_the_title();
        $output = $title . "<br />" . $thumbnail;
    }
    endforeach;
    $post = $temp_post;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return($output);

?>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php

global $post;
$temp_post = $post;
$args = array('numberposts' => 6, 'category' => 227, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC');
echo '<div class="categoryThumbnailList">';
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
    $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo '<div class="categoryThumbnailList_item">';
    echo '<a href="' .$link . '" title="' .$title . '">' .$thumbnail . '</a><br/>';
    echo '<a href="' .$link . '" title="' .$title . '">' .$title . '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
endforeach;
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="categoryThumbnailList_clearer"></div>';
$post = $temp_post;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

Comment: Your code appears to be trying the get the *post's* thumbnail with `get_post_thumbnail()`, not a category thumbnail. Are you using a plugin to set up category thumbnails? That would be a useful piece of information.

Comment: Got it. It should be `get_the_post_thumbnail()` - I forgot `the`

Comment: That still will get the thumbnail on a POST not a CATEGORY? Maybe I just misunderstood your question. If you've resolved your issue, please submit your answer and mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I'm trying to put this on my homepage where it already has a blog and loading posts with `the_posts()` - But my code takes place of the regular blog posts. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is it fair to say your question is "How to display the thumbnail for posts in a category?"

Comment: You're pulling in the latest 6 posts, are you sure they all have thumbnails? Perhaps it would be better to use WP_Query, and to do a meta query to only pull in posts that have featured images

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) is not appropriate here, it's stopping execution of the template. You should [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) your output.

Comment: thanks that helped a little bit. But it's still only outputting commas.